# Iterating through files is faster after the first time

Tags: python, file

This was something I came across while working on a project and I'm kind of confused. I have a `.txt` file with ~15000 lines. And when I run the program once, it takes around 4-5 seconds to go through all the lines. But I added a `while True` before opening the file and I did `file.close()` so that it continuously opens, goes through all the lines, and then closes.

But after the first run, I noticed that it takes around 1 second to complete. I made sure to close the files afterwards so what might be causing it to be so much faster?

Comment: Interesting. There are lots of layers of redundancy in the OS that could be producing this result, or it could be something in your code. Do you have a short runnable snippet of Python code that exhibits this behavior? Consider editing such a snippet into your question so that we can reproduce your behavior and better identify the source.

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "file caching" or "warming the cache".  All of the major operating systems allocate a goodly portion of your RAM to a file cache.  When you read a file, those buffers are retained for a while instead of being released right away.  If you read the same file again, it can often pull the data from RAM instead of going to disk.